# Teensy++ 2.0 doesn't jump into bootloader using software

Tags: bootloader, keyboard, teensy

I have a Teensy++ 2.0 with 90USB1286 CPU running QMK. I'm trying to make it jump into the bootloader using the QMK software. I tried two approaches:

1. Mapping a `RESET` keycode to a specific key - [docs](https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/using-qmk/simple-keycodes/quantum_keycodes#qmk-keycodes)
2. Using bootmagic bootloader command [docs](https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/using-qmk/advanced-keycodes/feature_command#configuration)

Neither of the two works. In both cases the Teensy just reboots but not into the bootloader.

Jumping into the bootloader by pressing reset button or shorting the RST and GND pins works as expected.

This is part of my `rules.mk`

```bash
MCU = at90usb1286

BOOTLOADER = halfkay
#BOOTLOADER_SIZE = 2048
```

I've found a github [issue](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/issues/532) about a different  Teensy needing to specify correct BOOTLOADER_SIZE because some Teensy clones uses nonstandard bootloader size. I tested almost all power of 2 values from 512 to 8192 for it but no luck. I'm starting to think I don't have genuine Teensy, but some clone which doesn't work even with the hint of BOOTLOADER_SIZE.

Any suggestions what should I try next?

Comment: I even tried putting `jump_bootloader();` into `process_record_user();` - this should force reboot into bootloader after any key press. Only reboot was performed. This demonstrates that my problem isn't a misconfiguration of bootmagic of keymap.